# Counting co-occurrence of levels of a variable within each level of another variable

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr, tidyverse

My `data` below has two columns (`studyID` & `post_id`). The column `post_id` has 4 unique values (`1 2 3 4`).

I was wondering how to determine how many times each unique value of `post_id` (e.g., `1`) co-occurs with another unique value of `post_id` (e.g., `2`) in each level of `studyID`?

For this data, the expected output should be a matrix with the *following* 6 unique elements `[row,col]` on its **lower-triangle** and `NA` everywhere else.

Is this possible to achieve in `R`?

Across all levels of `studyID`, `1` with `2` co-occurs 31 times. `[2,1]`

Across all levels of `studyID`, `1` with `3` co-occurs 3 times.  `[3,1]`

Across all levels of `studyID`, `1` with `4` co-occurs 1 time.   `[4,1]`

Across all levels of `studyID`, `2` with `3` co-occurs 3 times.  `[3,2]`

Across all levels of `studyID`, `2` with `4` co-occurs 1 time.   `[4,2]`

Across all levels of `studyID`, `3` with `4` co-occurs 1 time.   `[4,3]`

```
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ilzl/i/master/pr.csv")[c(1,7)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
`diag<-`(crossprod(table(data)>0), 0)

       post_id
post_id  1  2 3 4
      1  0 31 3 1
      2 31  0 3 1
      3  3  3 0 1
      4  1  1 1 0
```

Comment: Looks like I was 10mins too late (`Matrix::tril(crossprod(table(data)>0), -1)`). Great answer

Comment: @Reza. I am sorry but the code is self explanatory. The idea is rather mathematical in nature than programming. ie `crossprod` is a matrix multiplication. We count the number of relationships by simply dot multiplying the presence of post_id for each studyID

Comment: @rnorouzian Inteprate the results exactly as stated in the question. Note that it is a symmetric matrix

Comment: @rnorouzian Yes, in 31 levels, both 1 and 2 are present.

Comment: I came across a follow-up on your answer above. If I do `tab <- table(data); gg = colSums(tab)` what does `gg` gives? I think it gives the number of rows of `data` for occurrence of each level of `post_id` across all `studyID` levels. BUT, how can we get the number of rows of `data` for co-occurrence of each level of `post_id` (e.g., `1`) with another level of `post_id` (e.g., `2`) across all `studyID` levels?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by` to count the number of different values of `post_id` in each level of `studyID`, and for co-occurrence, only count how many times the number producd by `group_by` of pairwise `post_id` is equal (exclude 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ilzl/i/master/pr.csv")[c(1,7)]
data %>% 
  group_by(studyID) %>% 
  summarise(`1`=sum(post_id==1),
            `2`=sum(post_id==2),
            `3`=sum(post_id==3),
            `4`=sum(post_id==4)) -> a

mat <- matrix(rnorm(16),nrow = 4,ncol = 4)
rownames(mat) <- colnames(a)[2:5]
colnames(mat) <- colnames(a)[2:5]

for (i in colnames(mat)){
  for (j in rownames(mat)){
    tmp <- a %>% select(i,j)
    tmp[tmp == 0] <- NA 
    tmp <- na.omit(tmp)
    mat[i,j] <- sum(tmp[,i] == tmp[,j])
  }
}
mat[!lower.tri(mat, diag = FALSE)] <- NA
```